# NodeJs comparing two arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, filtering

For the record I am a relatively new programmer

I have the code working, but it seems clunky and slow if it were to sort through many items

granted, this node app does not need to be fast, i.e the process could take 5 min and it would be fine, but I was curious if there was a better way to do it...

I have this node app which is comparing two data sets... the goals of the program are as follows

1. compare the csv file to an online api
2. make sure all of the names in the csv file exist in the array
3. throw an error (console.log()) message to the screen instead of finishing

right now this is the code

```
const fs = require("fs");
const csv = require("csv-parser");
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

const results = [];

fs.createReadStream("./customers.csv")
  .pipe(csv())
  .on("data", (data) => {
    results.push(data);
  })
  .on("end", () => {
    console.log("Getting Customer Data from Waze...");
    fetch("https://gql.waveapps.com/graphql/public", {
      method: "post",
      headers: {
        //prettier-ignore
        'Authorization': "Bearer MyAuth",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        query: `
          query {
            business(id: "MyBusinessId") {
              customers {
                edges {
                  node {
                    id
                    name
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        `,
      }),
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(({ data }) => {
        console.log("Filtering Data...");
        // this maps through the csv file
        results.map((csv) => {
          let array = [];
          name = "";
          data.business.customers.edges.map((customer) => {
            // push the results of the expression (true of false) to an array
            array.push(
              customer.node.name.toLowerCase() === csv.name.toLowerCase()
            );
            // push nonexistent name (if there is one) variable so error handling is clear
            if (customer.node.name.toLowerCase() !== csv.name.toLowerCase()) {
              name = csv.name;
            }
          });
          // if all elements in array are false, that means there is no matching name in the data.business.customers.edges array and error will be true, if there is a true field in the name, return false
          const error = !array.some((el) => {
            if (el) {
              return true;
            }
          });

          if (error) {
            return console.log(
              `Name: ${name} not found in Waze customer list, please check your spelling`
            );
          }
          // send http request here
        });
        console.log("Finished Sending Invoices");
      });
  });
```

the customer.csv file

```
"name","domain","expiration-date"
"bob","yahoo.com","7/2/2020"
"suzie","google.com","12/1/2020"
```

right now the graphql api returns data that looks like this...

```
[
  {
    node: {
      id: 'QnVzaW5lc3M6MzE4NmRmNDQtZDg4Zi00MzgxLTk5ZGEtYTQzMWRmYzhmMDk5O0N1c3RvbWVyOjQ3NTg0Mzc2',
      name: 'NOInvoice'
    }
  },
  {
    node: {
      id: 'QnVzaW5lc3M6MzE4NmRmNDQtZDg4Zi00MzgxLTk5ZGEtYTQzMWRmYzhmMDk5O0N1c3RvbWVyOjQ3NTg0MzU3',
      name: 'Suzie'
    }
  },
  {
    node: {
      id: 'QnVzaW5lc3M6MzE4NmRmNDQtZDg4Zi00MzgxLTk5ZGEtYTQzMWRmYzhmMDk5O0N1c3RvbWVyOjQ3NTgwODkx',
      name: 'Bob'
    }
  }
]
```

any help would be appreciated greatly

Comment: well if you need the names of the properties that don't match, I don't see much way around it. You could JSON.stringify the two arrays and compare their results as an initial check, just to see if you need further examination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested maps = O(n*m) time complexity = poor performance

First create a hashmap of the names from the API, then scan the csv array and check each name against the hashmap to see if it exists or not.

Using a hashmap is a common way to improve the performance of nested loops. The result will be closer to O(n+m) time complexity, significantly more performant.

```
  // create hash of valid names from API
  const validNames = data.business.customers.edges.reduce(
    (names, customer) => { 
      names[customer.name] = customer;   /* or = true */
      return names; 
    }, 
    {}
  );

  // see if any of the names in the csv are not valid
  const err = results.reduce((err, csv) => validNames[csv.name] ? err: ++err, 0);
  if (arr > 0) {
    // have invalid names in CSV
  }

  // OR alternatively, find the invalid entries
  const invalid = results.reduce(
    (invalid, csv) => {
      if (!validNames[csv.name]) invalid.push(csv);
      return invalid;
    },
    []
  );
```

**EDIT**

```js
  // OR shorter version of find the invalid entries
  const invalid = results.filter(csv => !validNames[csv.name]);
  if (invalid.length) {
    // have invalid names in CSV
  }
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I completely forgot about the reduce method (which is awesome)

Not only is this easier to read and write, but also way faster, you're the man and

thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're using a lot of extra variables such as `array`, `name` and `error` that you actually don't need. So this not a performance optimization but an attempt to address the clunkiness of the code.
I'm pointing out some changes that you might consider.

```js
results.map((csv) => {
   customers_names = data.business.customers.edges.map((edge) => edge.node.name)
   if(!customers_names.some((name) => name === csv.name)) {
     console.log(`Name: ${csv.name} not found in Waze customer list, please check your spelling`)
   }
})
```

Instead of:

```js
results.map((csv) => {
  let array = []; <-- (1)
  name = ""; <-- (2)
  data.business.customers.edges.map((customer) => {
    // push the results of the expression (true of false) to an array
    array.push(
      customer.node.name.toLowerCase() === csv.name.toLowerCase()
    );
    // push nonexistent name (if there is one) variable so error handling is clear
    if (customer.node.name.toLowerCase() !== csv.name.toLowerCase()) {
      name = csv.name; <-- (3)
    }
  });
  // if all elements in array are false, that means there is no matching name in the data.business.customers.edges array and error will be true, if there is a true field in the name, return false
  const error = !array.some((el) => {
    if (el) {
      return true;
    }
  }); <-- (4)

  if (error) { <-- (5)
    return console.log(
      `Name: ${name} not found in Waze customer list, please check your spelling`
    );
  }
  // send http request here
});
```

**(1)** `array` keeps the `boolean` values that determines whether or not the `csv.name` was found in the data (`GraphQL` response). This `array` will be iterated on **(4)**. You don't really need two steps by iterating two different arrays, when you can actually find that out with the `some` function and comparing the names.

In **(2)** you define a variable `name`, and in **(3)** you keep updating that variable over and over again with the *same* value, which is `csv.name` (it doesn't change because it doesn't depend on `customer` at all). So I would remove that variable completely

**(5)** you only care about `csv.name` in the logs. So I'm doing exactly that in the shorter version